# Piping in windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have two files:

File1:

```
dir1
dir2
dir3
```

File2:

```
f1
f2
f3
```

File1 contains a list of directories and File2 contains a list of files. I want to copy all files in File2 which are in my current directory into directories mentioned in File1 using PowerShell. For doing the same I am using the following command:

```cs
Get-Content File2  | ForEach-Object {
    $dir = $_ ;
    Get-Content File1 |
        Copy-Item ("c:\users\")+$_ (("c:\users\")+$dir+("/")+($_)))
```

However, I am getting errors with this. Can someone please help me form the right query

The error which I am getting is:

> The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

I want f1, f2, f3 to be copied to dir1. Again f1, f2, f3 to be copied to dir2. And again f1, f2, f3 to be copied to dir3.

Comment: Could you please provide the errors you're getting.

Comment: Do you want something like the file `f1` should be copied to directory `dir1`, file `f2` to directory `dir2` and so on....?

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh I want all f1, f2, f3 to be copied to dir1. Again f1,f2,f3 to be copied to dir2, similarly

Comment: @GeorgeGrainger Done

Comment: **File1 contains a list of directories and File2 contains a list of files.** Is that a list or File1 actually contains dir1, dir2 & dir3?
Same question for File2.

Answer (score 3):

`Copy-Item` has only one parameter that accepts a source path as pipeline input: `-Path` (or `-LiteralPath`, depending on which parameter set is used). However, you're already passing a source path to `-Path` as the first positional parameter, so there's no parameter left that could accept the pipeline input. You cannot "overlay" positional parameters and pipeline input. It's either one or the other. Also, the `$_` in the `Copy-Item` statement is not what you expect. It's actually the current object from the `ForEach-Object`, not the current object from the `Get-Content` output. You'd need to pipe `Get-Content` into another `ForEach-Object` and put `Copy-Item` into that loop for it to work the way you expect. And as [Jeff Zeitlin pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718067/piping-in-windows-powershell/50718773?noredirect=1#comment88446952_50718773) in the comments, your directory names actually come from File1, so you need to read that file for the outer loop, and File2 (with the file names) for the inner loop.

```
Get-Content File1 | ForEach-Object {
    $dir = $_
    Get-Content File2 | ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item "C:\users\${_}" "C:\users\${dir}\${_}"
    }
}
```

However, that's not required in your scenario, since you could simple prepend the output of `Get-Content File1` with the path prefix and use that as input for `Copy-Item`:

```cs
Get-Content File1 | ForEach-Object {
    $dir = $_
    (Get-Content File2) -replace '^', 'C:\users\' |
        Copy-Item -Destination {'C:\users\{0}\{1}' -f $dir, (Split-Path -Leaf $_)}
}
```

Note that you need curly brackets around the argument of the parameter `-Destination` for this to work.

**Side note:** Avoid string concatenation wherever possible. PowerShell can expand variables inside double-quoted strings, which greatly improves readability.

Comment: If I'm reading the question correctly (and I'd want someone to verify it before I even thought of correcting your answer), it looks to me like you've swapped `File1` and `File2`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin How so? I literally took the code from the question and adjusted the individual commands, leaving the overall code structure as it was.

Comment: `File1` is the directories, and `File2` is the files. You're assigning the files to `$dir`. Desk-check your code, and cross-check vs. the question's prose, not necessarily just the code.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Ah, you're right. The code indeed had the files switched. Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.